# How to use List<String> as argument

Tags: java, android, arraylist, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm coding an Android app with [Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/start/) and want to write an object to the database:

```
public class newEvent {

public String whoEv;
public String whereEv;
public String whenEv;
public String whatEv;

public newEvent() {}

public newEvent(String whoEv, String whereEv, String whenEv, String whatEv) {
    this.whoEv = whoEv;
    this.whereEv = whereEv;
    this.whenEv = whenEv;
    this.whatEv = whatEv;
}
}
```

This works, but as you can see they are all 'just' strings. What i want is to have the first argument to be a List, Firebase doesnt allow String[] uploads/writings. 
The reason is to be able to pass more names into the `whoEv` as separated `Strings`/`Objects`. (to give each name a `boolean` if they are coming or not).
Now to the exact problem:

```
public newEvent(List<String> whoEv, String whereEv, String whenEv, String whatEv) {
    this.whoEv = whoEv;
    this.whereEv = whereEv;
    this.whenEv = whenEv;
    this.whatEv = whatEv;
}
```

When i use this, i have no clue how to write the proper code:

```
newEvent test = new newEvent(List<String>("derp","max"), "Amsterdam", "31/12/2016", "NewYears Eve");
```

The above obviously doesnt work. `Expression expected` or `unexpected token`. What am i missing or doing wrong? Already thanks for reading this!

Edit: Total idiot idea to use `List<String>`if i want to pass boolean values with the strings... Dont got clue what to use instead though.

Comment: You could try *java.util.Arrays.asList(..)* https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html

Comment: Try using this constructor - 1) public newEvent(ArrayList<String> whoEv, String whereEv, String whenEv, String whatEv) {}
2) newEvent test = new newEvent(new ArrayList<String>("derp","max"), "Amsterdam",

Comment: @Arjit It looks like that's the solution, even though i get an error: `Cannot resolve constructor 'ArrayList(java.lang.String, java.lang.String)`

Comment: Yeah, it will not work. You need to create an ArrayList<String> arr = new ArrayList<>();arr.add("derp");arr.add("max");
Pass this arr in to your constructor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed it:
`newEvent test = new newEvent("Meppel", "31/12/2016", "Oudjaarsdag", new String[]{"derp", "Sir", "max"});`

And in the class as:
`public class newEvent {

```
public ArrayList<String> wie;
public String waar;
public String wanneer;
public String wat;

public newEvent() {}

public newEvent(String waar, String wanneer, String wat, String... wie) {
    this.wie = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(wie));
    this.waar = waar;
    this.wanneer = wanneer;
    this.wat = wat;
}
```

Comment: This is pure for debugging and testing, thats why its so hardcoded.

Answer (score 0):

List is an Interface, you can't directly use it with out a implementation class. You can use one of default jdk provided classes which implements List interface. example ArrayList, LinkedList.

Go through this link on [List Implementations](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/implementations/list.html) and you will understand how you can pass a list of string as argument.

Comment: Could you explain this? I have no clue how to write the arguments: `new newEvent(["derp","max"],...`

Answer (score 0):

Is it Java? May be you need add the word "new" before **List**...
And don't forget **List** is an interface type, so here need use some inheritance class. **ArrayList** for example